# Push notification opens app automatically when unlocking an iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have developed the iPad app which uses apple push notification. Push notification delivering works fine in all the scenario except when the iPad device is locked and notification is delivered. In this scenario it behaves weirdly and opens the app when you slide to unlock the device without touching the alert/banner or notification from notification center.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{


     [self AgendaView];


}
-(void)AgendaView
{

    Agenda_Main *agendaview = [[Agenda_Main alloc]init];
    [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:agendaview animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Nothing weird about that. This is how iOS works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it this is the expected behavior. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature in iOS.. When u unlock the device, the most recent notification app will be opened..

Answer (score 0):

It works that way when first receiving the alert. If you let the device lock again after receiving it, when you unlock it the next time you will go to Springboard

Answer (score 0):

That is just how iOS works. You'll notice that when the alert comes in, the lock screen will only show information for that alert (it will also be centred on the vertical axis).

If you press the lock button to turn the screen off, then the home button to turn it back on you will see that the notification has now stacked to the top of the window, along with any other notifications. If you unlock the device now it will take you to the springboard, and not the app.